# Upload de arquivos grandes ou compactados?

Tags: php, arquivo, upload

Estou com um problema de envio de arquivos para o servidor para arquivos grandes e uma ideia foi enviar alguns deles de forma compactadas `.zip`.

Há algum problema em deixar aberto a parte de *upload* para o usuário poder enviar arquivos desse tipo?

Tem alguma outra solução para envio de arquivos grandes que passam do limite e com isso fica dando `time out`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não há problema algum neste tipo de extensão, pelo contrário. E se houvesse também, você estaria fazendo algo muito errado no seu *script*.

Para permitir o envio de arquivos maiores você pode mudar o arquivo `php.ini`. Procure por:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 32M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 32M
```

Se o problema é tempo, mude:

```
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
```

Pode ser que precise aumentar ainda mais. É bom não aumentar demais. E aí trate o problema, provavelmente usando a função [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

[Documentação](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: Eu tive essa dúvida mais por ver que alguns lugares não é permitida envio desse tipo de arquivo, mas já que não tem problemas vou fazer esse teste. E quanto as alterações do php.ini já fiz mas ainda assim continua.

Comment: É mais política interna. O que importa é o que tem dentro. O que ocorre é que els podem usar algum anti-vírus e o arquivo compactado pode impedir o av verificar. Embora todos que eu conheça conseguem ver dentro de zip. Melhorei a resposta.